# How do you configure 3rd party C# Roslyn analysers in an .editorconfig file (SonarLint, xUnit etc)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, roslyn-code-analysis, sonarlint, editorconfig

I'm trying to configure the SonarLint and xUnit analyzers in the .editorconfig file but I have no idea how.

I scoured both SonarLint and xUnit's docs and there's no indication on how to achieve this.

What am I missing?